# How to use component from module in entryComponents another module?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have `ngx-bootstrap` modal component. This modal is used inside `shared` folder. I use this `FirstModalComponent` in my `DashboardModule` like:

```
// Dashboard.module.ts
import { FirstModalComponent } from '../../shared/modals/first-modal/first-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FirstModalComponent 
  ]
});
```

And if I want to make my `FirstModalComponent` as module, how I should implement it in my `DashboardModule` and define it in `entryComponents`?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FirstModalModule } from './first-modal/first-modal.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FirstModalModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FirstModalModule
  ]
})
export class ModalsModule { }
```

Then I import/export this `ModalsModule` in `SharedModule` and trying to import shared module into `DashboardModule`.

How can I inject my `FirstModalComponent` to `entryComponents` in Dashboard now?

I get an error when I try to import `FirstModalComponent` and put to `entryComponents`: `Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules`.

P.S. I'm not sure that this is a good idea to make it as module..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be declaring the `FirstModalComponent` in only one `module`. It can be part of one module and exported by the same and can be defined as `entryComponent` for it's own module.

For your case, declare it as

`entryComponents: [
    FirstModalComponent 
  ]`

for the `FirstModalModule` and export the `FirstModalComponent` from `FirstModalModule`. It will work as expected when you import `FirstModalModule` inside `ModalsModule` or any other module in your application.

Make sure this `FirstModalModule` is exported by your `ModalsModule` and the `SharedModule` depending on your use. if you want to use it by importing `SharedModule` into your `DashboardModule`, this has to be exported from `SharedModule`.

Comment: glad it helped! :). Can you accept the answer, if it helped.

Comment: Was this answer made complex by intention? An easier answer would be. 
1. Create a `SharedModule`
2. Declare the modalComponent in that module. Add it to entryComponents as well.
3. Import the shared module where needed.
4. Done.

Comment: @Godhar, I was not sure if OP would like to have it in sharedModule since i didn't know the functionality. I gave both suggestions about adding it to it;s own module or add it to a `SharedModule`.

Comment: I appreciate that @nircraft , but other people are looking at this thread as well. I included a small workflow, this means we get both. Cheerio!