# Ionic: How do you use the same Modal-component on two different pages?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

My modules are set up like this, this is the config I am used to from classic Angular:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CreateBookingModule
  ],
  declarations: [PlaceDetailPage],
  entryComponents: [CreateBookingComponent]
})
export class PlaceDetailPageModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CreateBookingComponent],
  exports: [CreateBookingComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
  ]
})
export class CreateBookingModule { }
```

Unfortunately, when inside PlaceDetailPage and activating the Modal which is supposed to render CreateBookingComponent, I get the error:

`Error: No component factory found for CreateBookingComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

It only works if I have no CreateBookingModule at all and declare the component directly in PlaceDetailPageModule; but then I cannot use it in another component because a Component cannot be declared twice.

Comment: If I am not wrong it must add ex. app.module.ts like this:  `declarations: [CreateBookingComponent],` and `entryComponents: [CreateBookingComponent]`

Comment: create a common module which exports such components that you need in several modules. Then just import that common module to modules where you need it.

Comment: @Beller when I import it into app.module instead of the respective pages.module, I get runtime errors, that  CreateBookingComponent is not part of the module

Comment: @AJT82 CreateBookingModule is a SharedModule. As I said in the OP, the shared module approach doesn't work unfortunately (unless I am doing something wrong)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305259/how-to-use-component-from-module-in-entrycomponents-another-module

Answer (score 0):

I am closing the question because the problem was that it was a global (`providedIn: 'root'`) service that called ModalController to create a new modal.

I transformed the logic from the service into a directive. A directive always lives inside the parent component so I think this is a good way of making sure that modal problems do not escape into global DOM. Here is the directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCreateBooking]'
})
export class CreateBookingDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() placeToBook$: Observable<Place>;
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
  ) { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.placeToBook$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), tap(place => {
      this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        header: 'Choose an Action',
        buttons: [
          { text: 'Foo', handler: () => this.openBookingModal(place, 'foo') },
          { text: 'Bar', handler: () => this.openBookingModal(place, 'bar') },
          { text: 'Cancel', role: 'destructive' },
        ]
      }).then(el => el.present());
    })).subscribe();
  }

  private openBookingModal(place: Place, mode: PlaceDateSelectMode) {
    this.modalCtrl
      .create({
        // ...
      })
      .then(modal => {
        // ...
      });
  }
}
```